# Get specific values from a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I try to extract string values from this string:

`String str = "[{\"name:\"s2\"},{},{\"name\":\"f2\"},{\"name\":\"f2\"},{},{\"name\":\"l\"}]";`

I use regex to extract "s2", "f2", "f2" and "l".

I thought about a solutions, define a regex to find string that begin with ":" + a quotation mark and end with a quotation mark.

I'm not very familiar with regex but I assumed my regex would look like something like this ? `":\".?\""`

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\".?\"");

        String str = "[{\"name:\"s2\"},{},{\"name\":\"f2\"},{\"name\":\"f2\"},{},{\"name\":\"l\"}]";

        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        System.out.println(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("groupe = " + m.group());
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `.?` matches 1 or 0 chars.

Comment: Is the _javadoc_ for class [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) not clear? It details all the metacharacters that the class supports. Did you not understand the explanation about what each character does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use this pattern:

`"(?<=:")[^"]*"`

[See Demo](https://ideone.com/9yynX3)